# pointwise convergence almost everywhere implies convergence in measure

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove the following corollary:

Given a measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, such that $\mu(x)< \infty$. Then $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. implies $f_n \rightarrow f $in measure.

The definition of convergence in measure is that for all $\epsilon >0$
$\mu(\{x \in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}) \rightarrow 0$, if $n \rightarrow 0$.

So the idea seems to be, to show that, the measure of the sequence of sets $\{x \in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}$ converges to $0$.

I got the hint:
Define $E_n:=\{x \in X: |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}$ and notice that if $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ a.e., then the characteristic function of $E_n$ converges to $0$ pointwise almost everywhere.

Now I do not understand why $f_n$ converging to $f$ pointwise a.e. implies that $\chi_{E_n} $converges pointise a.e. to $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I do not understand why $f_n$
> converging to $f$
> pointwise a.e. implies that $\chi_{E_n}$ converges pointise a.e. to $0$.

This is by definition. Indeed, by definition we can find a co-null subset $A\subseteq X$ so that for every $\varepsilon>0$, and every $x\in A$, there exists some $N=N(x,\varepsilon)$ so that for all $n>N$, $|f_n(x) - f(x)|<\varepsilon$.

Therefore, by definition, for all $x\in A$, there exists some $N$ so that for all $n>N$ we have $\chi_{E_n}(x) = 0$. In particular, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\chi_{E_n}(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$.

Comment: What is a co-null subset? I am only familiar with null sets. Also, the definition that I am familiar with of pointwise convergence almost everywhere is $\mu(\{x \in X: f_n(x) \text{does not converge to f(x)} \})=0$. I can't follow your argumentation on how $\chi_{E_n} \rightarrow 0$ pointwise a.e. is implied by this definition. Could you maybe explain a little bit more?

Comment: so when something it true almost everywhere it means that it is true for a co-null set of points. co-null means that the complement (the set where the statement fails) is a null set. This is precisely what you wrote, so for us $A$ is the complement of the set from your comment.